how to train diffusion model using deepspeed
I'm trying to train an sd3 model with 4×3090, how can I optimize it with deepspeed? I get an error when I use ZeRO stage 3
I sincerely hope to get your help
Here are some information about the bug
error：
[rank2]: Traceback (most recent call last): [rank2]:   File "/hy-tmp/code/train_dreambooth_lora_sd3.py", line 1907, in <module> [rank2]:     main(args) [rank2]:   File "/hy-tmp/code/train_dreambooth_lora_sd3.py", line 1471, in main [rank2]:     instance_prompt_hidden_states, instance_pooled_prompt_embeds = compute_text_embeddings( [rank2]:   File "/hy-tmp/code/train_dreambooth_lora_sd3.py", line 1463, in compute_text_embeddings [rank2]:     prompt_embeds, pooled_prompt_embeds = encode_prompt( [rank2]:   File "/hy-tmp/code/train_dreambooth_lora_sd3.py", line 986, in encode_prompt [rank2]:     prompt_embeds, pooled_prompt_embeds = _encode_prompt_with_clip( [rank2]:   File "/hy-tmp/code/train_dreambooth_lora_sd3.py", line 955, in _encode_prompt_with_clip [rank2]:     prompt_embeds = text_encoder(text_input_ids.to(device), output_hidden_states=True) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl [rank2]:     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl [rank2]:     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py", line 1402, in forward [rank2]:     text_outputs = self.text_model( [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl [rank2]:     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl [rank2]:     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py", line 877, in forward [rank2]:     hidden_states = self.embeddings(input_ids=input_ids, position_ids=position_ids) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl [rank2]:     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl [rank2]:     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/clip/modeling_clip.py", line 225, in forward [rank2]:     inputs_embeds = self.token_embedding(input_ids) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl [rank2]:     return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl [rank2]:     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs) [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 164, in forward [rank2]:     return F.embedding( [rank2]:   File "/usr/local/miniconda3/envs/sd3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2267, in embedding [rank2]:     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse) [rank2]: RuntimeError: 'weight' must be 2-D 
**
zero_stage3_offload_config.json is below：**
{
    "fp16": {
        "enabled": true,
        "loss_scale": 0,
        "loss_scale_window": 1000,
        "initial_scale_power": 16,
        "hysteresis": 2,
        "min_loss_scale": 1
    },
    "optimizer": {
        "type": "AdamW",
        "params": {
            "lr": "auto",
            "weight_decay": "auto"
        }
    },
    "scheduler": {
        "type": "WarmupDecayLR",
        "params": {
            "warmup_min_lr": "auto",
            "warmup_max_lr": "auto",
            "warmup_num_steps": "auto",
            "total_num_steps": "auto"
        }
    },
    "zero_optimization": {
        "stage": 3,
        "offload_optimizer": {
            "device": "cpu",
            "pin_memory": true
        },
        "offload_param": {
            "device": "cpu",
            "pin_memory": true
        },
        "overlap_comm": true,
        "contiguous_gradients": true,
        "reduce_bucket_size": "auto",
        "stage3_prefetch_bucket_size": "auto",
        "stage3_param_persistence_threshold": "auto",
        "sub_group_size": 1e9,
        "stage3_max_live_parameters": 1e9,
        "stage3_max_reuse_distance": 1e9,
        "stage3_gather_16bit_weights_on_model_save": "auto"
    },
    "gradient_accumulation_steps": 1,
    "gradient_clipping": "auto",
    "steps_per_print": 2000,
    "train_batch_size": "auto",
    "train_micro_batch_size_per_gpu": "auto",
    "wall_clock_breakdown": false
}

default_config.yaml is below：
compute_environment: LOCAL_MACHINE
debug: true
deepspeed_config:
  deepspeed_config_file: /hy-tmp/zero_stage3_offload_config.json
  zero3_init_flag: true
distributed_type: DEEPSPEED
downcast_bf16: 'no'
enable_cpu_affinity: false
machine_rank: 0
main_training_function: main
num_machines: 1
num_processes: 4
rdzv_backend: static
same_network: true
tpu_env: []
tpu_use_cluster: false
tpu_use_sudo: false
use_cpu: false

About optimizer changes in train_dreambooth_lora_sd3.py
About lr_scheduler changes in train_dreambooth_lora_sd3.py
